# WebdriverIO invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am facing an issue selecting an element by going up the HTML dome with WebdriverIO. Note: It is easy to select the title by text and the h1 tag or by class name, but i don't want to do that.

Instead, i'd like the iframe tag to be my starting point and select it by partial src link text "nba-scores", then go back to the previous div with class="inner" OR to the div with class="main" **without** selecting it by class name and once i am on the previous div go to the h1 tag and get the text with pageTitle.getText().

When i use:

```
get pageTitle(){return $("//iframe[contains(@src, 'nba-scores')]/parent::div//h1)")}
```

I am getting a SyntaxError:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//iframe[contains(@src, 'nba-scores')]/parent::div//h1)' is not a valid XPath expression.

Here is my HTML dome

```
<main>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
       <h1 class="h1class">NBA Scores</h1>
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://xyz/#/nba-scores/view" class="viewscores">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</main>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have a syntax error with a stray `)` that is not opened and not necessary so change `"//iframe[contains(@src, 'nba-scores')]/parent::div//h1)"` to `"//iframe[contains(@src, 'nba-scores')]/parent::div//h1"`